# Asus RT-N10U router bricked after flashing firmware

Tags: router, dd-wrt, firmware

I tried to flash my Asus RT-N10U (the black version) with a DDWRT firmware. I followed all the steps from the website. I first uploaded the basic ddwrt-prepared firmware for this router model. Then, after restarting, a simple page showed up, with buttons to reset NVRAM and to upload new firmware. I pressed the reset and then started uploading the target firmware which I wanted to have on the router but it interrupted after a few seconds. I tried reuploading but it wouldn't. The only option left was resetting the NVRAM again which is what I did and after that the router died.

Firmware downloaded from here:
https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/?model=RT-N10U_BLACK_-
First flashed with "dd-wrt.v24-40559_NEWD-2_K2.6_mini_RT-N10U.trx" (DD-WRT: Factory flash). The tried with "dd-wrt.v24-40559_NEWD-2_K2.6_mega.bin" (DD-WRT Broadcom Generic - NEWD K2.6 - Mega).

And the flashing instructions I followed: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_RT-N10U#Installation_Instructions

When I switch it on I can see the LEDs shine with very dark light and absolutely nothing else happens. The router is not visible on the network, when connected via cable. Can't see its wifi AP.

I tried resetting with the physical reset button and also with the WPS button. I installed Asus Recovery and TFTP2 on my Windows client machine but I can't connect with the router so those apps can't help me.

Anyone has experience with this model/situation and knows what else I could try?

[image]

I've opened the case and can see a 4-pin connector on the PCB. According to the schematics it's a UART connector. Any advice on how to use this? Can I buy some cable to connect to a COM port on the PC and flash the firmware through UART?

[image]
[image]

Apparently there is a way to use the UART connector to communicate with the router. I just need to buy a cable.

Connecting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCwBvoueBG4

The cable: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-to-TTL-CP2102-UART-Module-5Pin-Serial-Convertor-5v-3-3v-FREE-Cables/262448073893?epid=22023081201&hash=item3d1b1fcca5:g:lhMAAOSwokVdMdA3

Comment: Sounds like you bricked your router, it also sounds like you didn’t successfully flash your device, hence the reason it was bricked.  DD-WRT Images are built against specific hardware, there are times, where a hardware revision will make DD-WRT incompatible with the hardware.

Comment: What version did you try to install? Which description did you follow? What's the actual model number?

Comment: I've updated the question with the link to where I got the firmware from

Comment: I guess you didn't read the dd-wrt FAQ section. The developers themselves state never to use the images in the router database, it's to check for **compatibility only**. The images are untested and bricksville/buggy as hell. You don't state whether you set a static IP address to try the Asus recovery, this is mandatory...

Comment: You also need to put it into **rescue** mode or the Asus utilities **will not work**. Let us know if you have already resolved this...

Comment: Still not solved. Yes, I did set a static IP and tried to put into rescue mode.
I've also bought one of those UART connectors and tried to get into the router's chip directly but no success either. It looks like it's connected but only displays some garbage in the response (I used Bray Terminal).